# Рамка вокруг изображения в QLabel

Tags: c++, qt

Есть `QLabel`, в который нужно запихнуть изображение. Нужно сделать так, чтобы это изображение отображалось с рамкой различной толщины. Как это можно сделать?
P.S. `QtStyleSheets` не подходит

Или, если есть лучший способ работы с изображениями в `Qt`, подскажите пожалуйста. Чтобы задача была понятнее, нужно отрисовать HTML тег `img` с его атрибутами средствами `Qt Widgets`. Очень слабо знаю `Qt`, а время поджимает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Класс `QLabel` наследуется от `QFrame`, а у последнего имеются методы установки [рамки](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qframe.html#Shape-enum), [стиля тени](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qframe.html#Shadow-enum), а также толщины линий ([тут](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qframe.html#lineWidth-prop) и [тут](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qframe.html#midLineWidth-prop)).

Но можно и вручную на виджете, переопределив соответствующий метод:

```
void MyWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {
    QPixmap pix("image.png");
    if(pix.isNull() == false) {
        QRect dst_rc = rect();

        if(dst_rc.width() > dst_rc.height())
            pix = pix.scaledToHeight(dst_rc.height());
        else if(dst_rc.height() > dst_rc.width())
            pix = pix.scaledToWidth(dst_rc.width());

        dst_rc = pix.rect();
        dst_rc.moveCenter(rect().center());

        const QBrush brush(Qt::black);

        const QPen pen(brush, 2); // Второй аргумент - толщина линии.

        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.setPen(pen);
        painter.setBrush(brush);
        painter.drawPixmap(dst_rc, pix);
        painter.drawRect(dst_rc);
    }

    event->accept();
}
```

... где `MyWidget` - наследник `QWidget`.